# Using str_detect to find a constant string and an optional end to the string

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm working on a project where I'm using case_when and str_detect to assign wrestling match results a particular tag for a new column. Sample code:

```
bruiser_record <- data_holder_brody %>% 
  mutate(
    win_or_lost =
      case_when(
        str_detect(
          details,
          "Bruiser Brody defeats | King Kong Brody defeats |
                   Red River Jack defeats | Frank Goodish defeats")
        & !str_detect(details, "DQ")
        & !str_detect(details, "Count Out")  ~ "win",
        str_detect(details, "defeats Bruiser Brody") 
        & !str_detect(details, "DQ") ~ "loss"
        ) 
  ) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  select(date, win_or_lost) %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(date))
```

Edit: Here is an example of what the data frame `data_holder_brody` looks like:

```
  number date       something details                                               
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                                                 
1      1 15.07.1988           Bruiser Brody and Stan Hansen defeat Jimmy Snuka and ~
2      2 13.07.1988           Bruiser Brody defeats Jumbo Tsuruta                   
3      3 05.05.1988           Bruiser Brody (c) defeats Abdullah the Butcher
```

I am using `str_detect` to assign `win` or `loss` to just find the singles matches from the `details` column (`defeats` indicates a singles match, whereas `defeat` indicates a multiple person match).

If the code is run with this dataframe, the result is:

```
date       win_or_lost
1988-07-13 win
```

My issue is that when someone is champ, a (c) comes after their name for that match result. So, to detect any wins that Bruiser Brody had as champion, I would need `str_detect(details, "Bruiser Brody (c) defeats")`.

I want to try and make this code efficient, and I don't want to have to double the code by putting a `(c)` in front of all of the `win` result strings in order to find out all of the matches he won as champion and non-champion.

I've been looking at the different ways to use stringr, but I'm not seeing an easy way to have a string with an optional end, where it will detect with or without the optional snippet of string.

My best guess is below:

```
  mutate(
    win_or_lost =
      case_when(
        str_detect(
          details,
          "Bruiser Brody defeats ((c)) | King Kong Brody defeats |
                   Red River Jack defeats | Frank Goodish defeats")
        & !str_detect(details, "DQ")
        & !str_detect(details, "Count Out")  ~ "win",
        str_detect(details, "defeats Bruiser Brody") 
        & !str_detect(details, "DQ") ~ "loss"
      ) 
  ) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  select(date, win_or_lost) %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(date))
```

But it just winds up with no observations in the return dataframe.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you reformat this into a reproducible example? https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html Ideally with some of the data you want to use included as something other than a picture. The code you've pasted so far includes some syntax errors that likely are a result of mixing single and double quotes but at present it's quite difficult to read.

Comment: Hey edavidaja, I just put in a more readable dataframe per the link you provided. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you looking to count? Bruiser Brody wins? Anyway, be aware that parentheses are used to group strings. To get around this, use ` \\ ` before the symbol. Like so:
`df %>% 
  mutate(Bruiser_Champ_win_or_lost = case_when(
    str_detect(details,'Bruiser Brody \\(c\\)') ~ 'Champ Win',
    T ~ 'Non Champ-Win'
  ))`